# How to batch check audio files can play

Tags: audio, batch, verification

Background:

I have ripped my CD collection to FLAC but I had a drive error which were repaired with the standard windows tool. Error was likely due to unplugging before safe removal.

I want to be able to quickly check that the files are playable, without going through each one.

One way I can think of is to use dbPowerAmp to batch convert them to another format, e.g. AAC - if any of them are unplayable then it would be likely that dbPowerAmp would not be able to convert I would think.

Can anyone provide a better solution?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FLAC files ensure audio data integrity by storing an MD5 signature of the original unencoded audio data in the file header. You can quickly check for decoding errors by using [FLAC](https://xiph.org/flac/download.html)'s **-t** or **--test** option, like so:

```
flac -t *.flac
```

If you use foobar2000, you can use the [File Integrity Verifier](http://www.foobar2000.org/components/view/foo_verifier) component for the same purpose.